# UITextView setText works only once

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextview

I have a UITextView in my xib and in my UIViewController class, I call setText on this element.  It works correctly - once.

Subsequently, it does not set the text and the old text remains.

I also have the same problem with UINavigationBar, where navBar.topItem.title can be set once but not again.

How do I clear the old values and get the new values to show?

Thanks
DeShawn

Comment: Could you post the code you are setting the text in?

Answer (score 0):

Does 'subsequently' mean 'on the next line of code' or 'the next time a button is clicked' ?
The latter is appropriate I guess, don't you set your outlet to nil somewhere ?